# Javascript how to allow period in script that removes everything except numbers?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code i would like to have period "." be allowed to be entered. The code right now only allows numbers. What needs to be changed to allow this to happen?

```
function check(o)
{
    v=o.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,''); // remove any whitespace
    if(o=='') {
        return;
    }
    v=v.substr(v.length-1);
    if(v.match(/\d/g)==null) {
        o.value=o.value.substr(0,o.value.length-1).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
    }
};
```

Also do you see if there is a more efficient way to write this code? Can any optimizations be made to it? I simply would like to allow only numbers and periods to be entered.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a duplicate to: [regular expression to allow only integer and decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12475704/1960455)

Comment: Well,  you could use `trim` to remove leading and trailing whitespace. Change your regex to allow periods?

Comment: this code above does not remove "." from the entered value so what is the issue.

Comment: Your welcome to try it yourself Suchit https://jsfiddle.net/jxjmvao6/

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use this regex to match numbers and or periods: `/(\.\d)*/`

Source: the MDN page on String.prototype.match https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: I should replace if(v.match(/\d/g)==null with if(v.match(/(\.\d)*/)==null)? That seems to allow letters to be entered now.

Answer (score 0):

This line trims whitespaces at the beginnig **or** at the end of the string and assigns it to v:

```
v=o.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
```

This line assignes the last symbol of v back to v:

```
v=v.substr(v.length-1);
```

This esxpression checkes if this last symbol is not a digit:

```
v.match(/\d/g)==null
```

And if it is not a digit, it makes the o.value have its value but trimmed and without that last digit.

```
o.value=o.value.substr(0,o.value.length-1).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
```

If you are asking about efficiency of this code, at the first place it's not efficient from the point of view of the code's readability and supportability. For despite of the function's name 'check' it does a lot of different things except giving back the result of the check.

If you want to check if the last non-whitespace symbol of the input is digit/dot or not, the function would be:

```
function endsWithDigit(input) {
   return input.trim().match(/[0-9\.]$/);
}
```

If you want to remove that last symbol if it is not a digit:

```
function removeNotDigit(input) {
    if (!endsWithDigit(input) {
        return input.replace(/.\s*$/, '');
    } esle {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Or you can just write the last function without explicit check:

```
function removeNotDigin(input) {
    return input.replce(/[0-9\.]\s*$/, '');
}
```